# Failed to load ApplicationContext of Spring web app

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I need a solution of a small problem. I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4wD80_0jWI) tutorial and this [source code](https://github.com/chrishenkel/spring-angularjs-tutorial-6) . I'm using maven,eclipse for the tutorial and using default maven structure. I put everything the way in this tutorial are. So, my class structure is like this

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources/spring/business-config.xml
src/test/java/tutorial/core/repositories/AccountRepoTest.java
```

here is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/business-config.xml")
public class AccountRepoTest {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepo repo;

    private Account account;

    @Before
    @Transactional
    @Rollback(false)
    public void setup(){
        account=new Account();
        account.setName("name");
        account.setPassword("password");
        repo.createAccount(account);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testFind(){
        assertNotNull(repo.findAccount(account.getId()));
    }
}
```

Problem is when I run the test, it is showing Application context is failed to load. But I've done everything according to the tutorial and in the video tutorial everything showing ok.Other tests of this tutorial,which are not using ApplicationContext are running fine.I'm assuming there is some problem in my eclipse classpath. I want to know,how can I fix this? I've given my business-config.xml and console output below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="tutorial.core.repositories.jpa" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="sa" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdaptor">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateVendorAdaptor" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="tutorial.core.model.entities" />
    </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />
</beans>
```

console output:

```
Dec 29, 2014 10:16:03 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager retrieveTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttributeSource]
Dec 29, 2014 10:16:05 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]
Dec 29, 2014 10:16:10 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@d1af89] to prepare test instance [tutorial.core.repositories.AccountRepoTest@646db9]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:253)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: what's the content of business-config.xml?

Comment: I've added it with the question. @almas shaikh

Comment: are you using mvc feature of spring and transaction manager anywhere?

Comment: I've run my controller test using mockmvc. But I didn't use transaction manager there. I'm using transaction manager here for the first time in this tutorial.

Comment: Please remove `<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />`, `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd` from your xml and retry.

Comment: I've done it,but result is same.

Comment: Please remove `xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx` as well.

Comment: I did that too. @almas shaikh

Comment: Is the error message same like `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]`

Comment: Actually I tried all possible solution of this problem I found. I've added the jar manually to. But all the time result is same.

Comment: i bet you have somewhere old xml in your classpath or you changed wrong xml! Try deleting you xml and rerun it and see it would again give you same error.

Comment: How are you running your tests?

Comment: Thanx, But my problem solved when I imported spring ORM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for all my JUnit tests. You may not need the @WebAppConfiguration. You may or may not want to wire in those @PropertySrouce files but trust me they come in handy.

Right click- >Properties on the context file to make sure you have the correct path.

Good Luck!

```css
@Configuration
    @PropertySource(value={
  "classpath:usermgmt.properties",
  "classpath:ldap.properties",
  
     })
     @ContextConfiguration(locations = {
  "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml",
  "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext-email.xml",
  "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext-jdbc.xml"
  
   })
   @WebAppConfiguration
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   public class ClassTest {

   }
```

Just an update for those using Springboot I got caught up on JUnit and Boot.
Here is what you need for JUnit and Springboot:

```css
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ExampleApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class ExampleApplicationTests {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your exception, it seems like you are missing the spring transaction jar.

add jar : spring-tx.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx

Comment: I've added it.But problem still exists.